# Mathematica doesn't evaluate LinearSolve Function properly

Tags: functions, evaluation, linear-algebra, output-formatting

Maybe this could be a stupid question, but I can't solve this problem.
I'm trying to evaluate an expression with LinearSolve Function but it doesn't work.

I have pre-evaluated the matrix matriceRigidezza which is [5x5] and the array terminiNoti which is [5x1]. Then I tryed to calculate vector dsol which is solution of the linear sistem matriceRigidezza.dsol==terminiNoti.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
terminiNoti = -terminiNoti // MatrixForm;
matriceRigidezza // MatrixForm;
dsol = LinearSolve[matriceRigidezza, terminiNoti]
```

And here is the output:
[image]

I'd like to have the numerical solution instead of the repetition of the instruction.
If someone could help me I really thank you.

Comment: This is a common mistake about `MatrixForm`. This function should not be used when defining matrices, but only for printing them as output. See item number 8 [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/43522)

Comment: I've just tryed and it works, thank you very much!